# how to set combobox display member and value member by split string

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have List which stores database name and connection string separated by a comma. I want to set the database name as display member and connection string as value member to a combo box.

```
Private void BindDataCombobox(){
List<string> conString =new List<string>();
conString.Add("Database1,'server=server1'");
conString.Add("Database2,'server=server2'");
conString.Add("Database3,'server=server3'");
conString.Add("Database4,'server=server4'");
combobox1.Datasource=conString;
combobox1.DisplayMember="I want to set this to hold Database1,Database2,...etc values";
combobox1.ValueMember="I want this to hold server1,server2,server3....etc";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("db",typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("server",typeof(string));
foreach(string s in constring)
{
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["db"]=s.Split(',')[0]; 
dr["server"]=s.Split(',')[1].Split('=')[1].Replace("'",string.Empty);
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
combobox1.DataSource=dt;
combobox1.DisplayMember="db"; combobox1.ValueMember="server" ;
```

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the ComboBox to a Dictionary:

```
        List<string> conString = new List<string>();

        conString.Add("Database1,'server=server1'");
        conString.Add("Database2,'server=server2'");
        conString.Add("Database3,'server=server3'");
        conString.Add("Database4,'server=server4'");

        var comboDataSource = conString.ToDictionary(c => c.Split(',')[0], c => c.Split(',')[1]);

        comboBox2.DataSource = new BindingSource(comboDataSource, null);
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Key";
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "Value";
```